# Java 7 New Feature String datatype in Switch case

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, java-7

Is there any need to Override equals() method to used String datatype in Switch case

Comment: aahhhh....... no. It will work just fine as is.

Comment: no...................

Comment: You can't even override any methods in String. String is final.

Answer (score 3):

Not only you don't need to do this, you simply can't (`String` is `final`).

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to use `String` in your `Switch` statement then it's better to use
[ENUM TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)